# java complex enum pass by reference to a given method

Tags: java, enums

Ok, this is the example. I know this requirement can be covered in a better way, please see it as an example to illustrate the need.

Module1Messages and Module2Message are the enums. The intention is to have a method (getAllModuleMessages) to get all the messages from any module in a json array structure.

Once this said, and the things that can be improved are:

The internal getMessagesAndCodes in each enum are clones, just the reference to its own enum is what differ. Is possible to move it out and be unique receiving the enum from where you want to perform this action?

In getAllModuleMessages, the list of enums is static. Is it possible to get the list by family?

I read that maybe what I'm looking for is a Interface. Can you introduce me in Interfaces for enums? will it resolve all those needs?

Thanks again

```
public enum Module1Messages{MOD1_MESSAGE_1("Message 1 for module 1", "Mensaje 1 para modulo 1");
    private Module1Messages(String msgCodeEn, String msgCodeEs){
        this.message_en=msgCodeEn;
        this.message_es=msgCodeEs;
    }
    public String getMessageEN(){return this.message_en;}
    public String getMessageES(){return this.message_es;}
    public static JSONArray getMessagesAndCodes(){
        JSONArray jArr=new JSONArray();
        for (Module1Messages curMsgCode: Module1Messages.values()){
            JSONObject jObj=new JSONObject();
            jObj.put("message_code", curMsgCode.name());
            jObj.put("English", curMsgCode.message_en);
            jObj.put("Spanish", curMsgCode.message_es);
            jArr.add(jObj);
        }
        return jArr;
    }    
    private final String message_en;
    private final String message_es;
}

    private Module2Messages(String msgCodeEn, String msgCodeEs){
        this.message_en=msgCodeEn;
        this.message_es=msgCodeEs;
    }
    public String getMessageEN(){return this.message_en;}
    public String getMessageES(){return this.message_es;}
    public static JSONArray getMessagesAndCodes(){
        JSONArray jArr=new JSONArray();
        for (Module2Messages curMsgCode: Module2Messages.values()){
            JSONObject jObj=new JSONObject();
            jObj.put("message_code", curMsgCode.name());
            jObj.put("English", curMsgCode.message_en);
            jObj.put("Spanish", curMsgCode.message_es);
            jArr.add(jObj);
        }
        return jArr;
    }        
    private final String message_en;
    private final String message_es;
}

public  JSONArray getAllModuleMessages(){
    JSONArray jArr=new JSONArray();
    jArr.add(Module1Messages.getMessagesAndCodes());
    jArr.add(Module2Messages.getMessagesAndCodes());
    return jArr;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think what you are trying to do is you own implementation for localization / message resources? You could take a look e.g. at https://www.baeldung.com/java-localization-messages-formatting

Comment: No, I'm using this topic to illustrate through the example a situation that I want to refactor as said in the first phrase " I know this requirement can be covered in a better way, please see it as an example to illustrate the need". The question is about how to move the cloned method in both enums to become a one only method invoked to get the data for the first enum or the second or any other extra enum build in the same way passing the enum by reference. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your enums can implement Interfaces as you've said, for this particular example it would be something like:

```
public interface LanguageMessages {
  String getCode();
  String getEnglish();
  String getSpanish();
}

public enum Module1Messages implements LanguageMessages {
  ...

  getCode() { return name() }
  getEnglish() { return messageEn; } // naming conventions
  getSpanish() { return messageSp; } 
}

public enum Module2Messages implements LanguageMessages {
  ...

  getCode() { return name() }
  getEnglish() { return messageEn; } // naming conventions
  getSpanish() { return messageSp; } 
}
```

There is obviously a little bit of overlap, but now you can loop through your values as `LanguageMessages`:

```
    public static JSONArray getMessagesAndCodes(LanguageMessages[]... messages){
        JSONArray jArr=new JSONArray();        
        
        for (LanguageMessages[] currMessages: messages){
            for (LanguageMessages message : currMessages) {
                JSONObject jObj=new JSONObject();
                jObj.put("message_code", message.getCode());
                jObj.put("English", message.getEnglish());
                jObj.put("Spanish", message.getSpanish());
                jArr.add(jObj);     
            }
        }
        return jArr;
    }
```

Now just figure out how you actually want to call it:

- `getMessagesAndCodes(Module1Messages.values(), Modul2Messages.values());`
- or some other way to flatten the list

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for the first 'refactoring'.

Comment: Do you know any way to get a list/array of enums that implements the same interface for a given project? The intention is to run this method  for all the enums for this interface without having to add it manually to a list any time one new enum is added 'to the family'

Comment: For that you'd need to use an injected provider or the have service provider.

Comment: Agree, do you know which provider? I found some techniques like the one to get the method caller even from which line the method is being called and they work by injection but no idea where I can find the same for enums. Thanks @kendavidson

Comment: I worked with classPath developer to provide reflection methods for what I was looking for, I mean to get all enums implementing the same interface and at the same time the way to invoke its own methods by reflection.